# Loading xml from memory with Xerces

Tags: c++, xml, file, memory, xerces

I got some sensible xml data I'd like to parse with Xerces (generated by CodeSynthesis).

On disc it is crypted so I load it, uncrypt it and ... I'm stuck as Xerces only takes files as input.

I have thought about overloading one of the 'readers' (ie. std::istream or xercesc::InputSource) and fake the disc reading but it seems as quirky as inelegant.

Are there any simpler and neater way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `MemBufInputSource` class:

```
MemBufInputSource* pMemBufIS = new MemBufInputSource((const XMLByte*)sXmlContent.c_str(), sXmlContent.length(), "SysID", false);
m_saxParser.parse(*pMemBufIS);
delete pMemBufIS;
```

instead of

```
m_saxParser.parse(sXmlFilePath.c_str());
```

Comment: There is no need to allocate `MemBufInputSource` dynamically, just use it on the stack as is.